# Hello i'm having this issue when trying to start stencil

Tags: npm, bigcommerce

$ stencil start

### There is an issue with `node-fibers`

`` `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.24.1\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\fibers\bin\win32-x64-64\fibers.node` is missing. ``

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to your theme directory and then run `npm install`. Running this command should add the missing JavaScript library dependencies.

If you receive the same error again after running `npm install`, you should completely uninstall and reinstall both the Stencil framework and Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, I ran into this error and found I was using node 14.20.0 instead of 14.0.0. Here's how I resolved:

```
nvm uninstall 14.20.0 // I only need version 14 for stencil
nvm install 14.0.0
nvm use 14.0.0

//cd ~/path/to/theme/dir

npm install
stencil start
```

Answer (score 0):

The last version of Stencil CLI `5.2.4`, uses node 14: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli

> Note: Stencil requires the Node.js runtime environment, version 14.x
> is supported. We do not yet have support for versions greater than
> Node 14.

`npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`